# Proving that $\limsup {x_{n}} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ( \sup _ {m \geq n} x_{m} )$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Proving that $\limsup {x_{n}} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ( \sup _ {m \geq n}  x_{m} )$.

I want to prove it using only the definition of the $\limsup {x_{n}}$: that $\limsup 
 {x_{n}}$ is the largest accumulation point of $\{x_{n}\}$.

I have seen many links for the proof here but as far as I understand not directly from this definition and after reading them all I got confused, could any one help me in proving this?

Comment: So do you want to prove that $\limsup {x_{n}} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ( \sup _ {m \geq n}  x_{m} )$ using some other definition, or do you want to use this as a definition, and prove that $\limsup {x_{n}} $ is the largest accumulation point of $\{x_n\}$?

Comment: I have read this question and I did not understand the solution @Holo and I do not feel that they are the same

Comment: @hopefully so please add what didn't you understand to the question, and why do you think it is different

Comment: @Holo for example in my question I did not mention at all equation (1) in you suggested link